# Symfony2 bootstrap twig include

Tags: css, symfony, twitter-bootstrap, twig

I tried to install **Twitter Bootstrap** on Symfony2 2.3 following this simple tutorial:
http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/getting-started

All appears successfully installed, in fact checking into the *vendor* folder, there are the *braincrafted*, *jquery* and *twitter* ones.

Then, how i can call the bootrstrap .css (or .less) files into my .twig ones?
Probably i'm mistaking some steps or stupid thing but in that tutorial i don't see a way to make it.

I thought a thing like below but maybe i'm in wrong:

```
<link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to add lessphp to your composer.json.

then do a composer.phar update

then In the section With Assetic use the lessphp method.

At this moment : php app/console assetic:dump

To finish include the  files as Alain Tiemblo said.

Comment: Thank you Ybert.
That's perfect!! In fact i had already done what Alain Tiemblo wrote but the lost step was just to input the assetic:dump:
`php app/console assetic:dump`.
Now it works! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the bootstrap inclusion between your `<head>` tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}">
```

And at the bottom of your file, just before the `</body>` tag, include required scripts:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
```